# How to get label above checkbox

Tags: yii2

I am creating a form in Yii2, but have some issues with the default design. Namely, `<?= $form->field($model, 'x')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>` will place the 'x' label above the textfield, but `<?= $form->field($model, 'y')->checkbox(['label' => 'y'])  ?>` places the label to the right of the box. Since this isn't some html element that I can just adjust with css (afaik?), I have no idea how to fix it and get the label above the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `false` as second argument to [`checkbox()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#checkbox()-detail):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'y')->label('y')->checkbox([], false) ?>
```

You still may need to adjust CSS (that depends on your layout styles), but checkbox and its label will be rendered using standard field layout, sot is should be fairly easy.